# LLDB debugger - how to evaluate C macros?

Tags: xcode, gdb, lldb

I am trying to debug an application that makes extensive use of C macros (nested macros of macros).  It gives  "use of undeclared identifier" error.

Is there any way to make LLDB debugger recognize and evaluate it properly?  I can decompose the macros myself and write the full expression but it's very tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is not gonna happen because we get no debug info for macros from the compiler, which kinda makes sense because macros disappear after the preprocessor does its deed and before the compiler converts your sources to machine code.

Comment: Yeah, none of the macro information is represented in the debug info from clang - it adds a lot more data to the (already large) debug info.  I think some versions of gcc are emitting in their DWARF.  By the time lldb is running on your program, the macros and `#defines` are not available at all.

Comment: Nowadays, adding `-g3` when compiling adds macro information such that you can do `info macro NAME` to get information on a macro.

Comment: @PhilippeCarphin I think you're describing `gdb` here, right? The question refers to `lldb` - it doesn't have `info macro` command and I still couldn't find an option to expand macros live in `lldb`.

Comment: @mtsokol Yes, well I wanted to point out the `-g3` which makes it possible for a debugger to access macro information because this answer was explaining that it was impossible.   As you said, `info macro NAME` is a `gdb` command and I haven't been able to find its equivalent in lldb.

Comment: @mtsokol Just ran some tests.  I had incorrectly assumed that since clang doesn't complain about `-g3` it would add macro information like gcc does but it does not: For a C program compiled with `clang -g3`, gdb is unable to show info on macros while it can do it for the same code compiled with `gcc -g3`.  Kind of a bummer but I think we can hope that clang, llvm, lldb might implement these features in the future.

Comment: @PhilippeCarphin Actually using `-ggdb3 -fdebug-macro` with `clang` you can show info on macro on `gdb`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77840581/debug-preprocessor-macro-in-clang