# Debug Preprocessor Macro in clang

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, clang

It seems that I cannot get information on all the preprocessor macros of a `clang` program from `gdb`.

Consider this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO_B   2

int main()
{
    printf("MACRO A: %d\n", (int) MACRO_A);
    printf("MACRO B: %d\n", (int) MACRO_B);
    return 0;
}
```

I define `MACRO_A` on the command line with:

```
clang -ggdb3 -fdebug-macro -DMACRO_A=1 -o test test.c
```

According to the [documentation](https://releases.llvm.org/12.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html), the option `-fdebug-macro` should be enough to add information on both `MACRO_A` and `MACRO_B`, however using `gdb` I cannot access to information on `MACRO_A`:

```
(gdb) info macro MACRO_B
Defined at /data/work/external/developer/SO/debug_preprocessing_macro_clang/test.c:3
#define MACRO_B 2
(gdb) info macro MACRO_A
The symbol `MACRO_A' has no definition as a C/C++ preprocessor macro
at /data/work/external/developer/SO/debug_preprocessing_macro_clang/test.c:7
```

I'm using `clang version 12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.5` and `gdb 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1`.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this relates to [this GDB bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29034) which relates to handling of macros defined on the command line when using Clang.

This bug was fixed in GDB 13 and later, so I think the answer is, update GDB.

When I use GDB 14, and Clang 15, I see this behaviour:

```
(gdb) info macro MACRO_A
Defined at /tmp/clang-macro/test.c:0
-DMACRO_A=1
(gdb) info macro MACRO_B
Defined at /tmp/clang-macro/test.c:3
#define MACRO_B 2
```

Comment: Thanks! Although it seems that only updating `GDB` to 14.1 doesn't solve the issue. I had to update `clang` too.

Answer (score -1):

C pre-processor macros are not included in your output program. When the program is compiled, the c pre-processor runs through the file, and substitutes the literal text `1` or `2` for `MACRO_A` and `MACRO_B`. It then takes the resulting file, and complies the code. When you ask gdb for macro information, it isn't looking in the output file, but it reads your source code, and finds the macro there. Because `MACRO_A` is not in your source code, it cannot be found.

If you really want a global value that GDB can find later, consider using `static const int MY_GLOBAL_A = MACRO_A`. The macro can be given on the commandline, and gdb should be able to resolve `MY_GLOBAL_A`.

Comment: `MACRO_A` is being printed

Comment: @jxh I don't understand your point. Yes it is being printed. That does not change anything

Comment: @Carson compiling the code with `gcc -ggdb3 -DMACRO_A=1 -o test test.c` i can have information on both macro.

Comment: You had a statement *Because `MACRO_A` is not in your source code ...*.